# Why does the old() method not work in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

My environment is Laravel 6.0 with PHP 7.3. I want to show the old search value in the text field. However, the `old()` method is not working. After searching, the old value of the search disappeared. Why isn't the old value displayed? I researched that in most cases, you can use `redirect()->withInput()` but I don't want to use `redirect()`. I would prefer to use the view(). method

**Controller**

```php
class ClientController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $clients = Client::orderBy('id', 'asc')->paginate(Client::PAGINATE_NUMBER);

        return view('auth.client.index', compact('clients'));
    }

    public function search()
    {
        $clientID = $request->input('clientID');
        $status = $request->input('status');
        $nameKana = $request->input('nameKana');
        $registerStartDate = $request->input('registerStartDate');
        $registerEndDate = $request->input('registerEndDate');

        $query = Client::query();
        if (isset($clientID)) {
            $query->where('id', $clientID);
        }
        if ($status != "default") {
            $query->where('status', (int) $status);
        }
        if (isset($nameKana)) {
            $query->where('nameKana', 'LIKE', '%'.$nameKana.'%');
        }
        if (isset($registerStartDate)) {
            $query->whereDate('registerDate', '>=', $registerStartDate);
        }
        if (isset($registerEndDate)) {
            $query->whereDate('registerDate', '<=', $registerEndDate);
        }
        $clients = $query->paginate(Client::PAGINATE_NUMBER);

        return view('auth.client.index', compact('clients'));
    }
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::get('/', 'ClientController@index')->name('client.index');
Route::get('/search', 'ClientController@search')->name('client.search');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "old method"?

Comment: @NicoHaase There's a Laravel method called `old()` that shows the "old" input when using `->withInput()` on a `redirect()` call.

Comment: so in the auth.client.index view you want to prefill again the forms with the submitted data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to pass the variables back to the view:

In `Controller`:

```
public function search(Request $request){
  $clientID = $request->input('clientID');
  $status = $request->input('status');
  $nameKana = $request->input('nameKana');
  $registerStartDate = $request->input('registerStartDate');
  $registerEndDate = $request->input('registerEndDate');

  ...

  return view('auth.client.index', compact('clients', 'clientID', 'status', 'nameKana', 'registerStartDate', 'registerEndDate'));
}
```

Then, in your index, just do an `isset()` check on the variables:

In `index.blade.php`:

```
<input name="clientID" value="{{ isset($clientID) ? $clientID : '' }}"/>
<input name="status" value="{{ isset($status) ? $status : '' }}"/>
<input name="nameKana" value="{{ isset($nameKana) ? $nameKana : '' }}"/>
...
```

Since you're returning the same view in both functions, but only passing the variables on one of them, you need to use `isset()` to ensure the variables exist before trying to use them as the `value()` attribute on your inputs.

Also, make sure you have `Request $request` in your method, `public function search(Request $request){ ... }` (see above) so that `$request->input()` is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you load your view and pass in the array as argument.

```
// Example:
// Create a newarray with new and old data
$dataSet = array (
    'clients'           => $query->paginate(Client::PAGINATE_NUMBER),
    // OLD DATA
    'clientID'          => $clientID,
    'status'            => $status,
    'nameKana'          => $nameKana,
    'registerStartDate' => $registerStartDate,
    'registerEndDate'   => $registerEndDate
);

// sent dataset
return view('auth.client.index', $dataSet);
```

Then you can access them in your view as variables `$registerStartDate` but better to check if it exists first using the `isset()` method.

example `<input type='text' value='@if(isset($registerStartDate)) {{registerStartDate}} @endif />`